# error using paramiko module of Python

Tags: python, import, zlib, paramiko

Ia m using Python 2.7.6 and installed paramiko module. When I import it on CLI, I get  "zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data;zlib not available".

I installed python-devel module but it looks like it is getting installed for Python 2.6.6 - the older version on the same system.

When I do "sudo yum install python-devel", I get "Package python-devel-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 is already installed and lates version. Nothing to do".

Can someone help please? How do I install python-devel for 2.7.6 and import paramiko module without issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have zlib module installed?

Comment: Yes, I have "zlib-devel", "zlib" and "zlib-static". I need to find how to install python-devel for Python 2.7.6 instead of how its getting installed for Python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed python using https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/Installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-Follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only  and it worked fine. I think the existing version of Python 2.6.6 and my new version Python 2.7.6 got mixed up -- so creating symbolic links to Python 2.7.6 and installation of "Development tools" and other packages helped.